# android - failed to insert data to server in android through php script

Tags: php, android

I want to insert data to server using `PHP` script in android but when I click `button` to insert, I got an error in logcat.

Did I doing wrong?

i get the same output of `D/output lines: {"success":0} ; I/System.out: success=0` because when button clicked, it goes to loop for 5 times.

all the code used below:

`logcat error :`

```
D/output lines: {"success":0}
I/System.out: success=0
D/output lines: {"success":0}
I/System.out: success=0
D/output lines: {"success":0}
I/System.out: success=0
D/output lines: {"success":0}
I/System.out: success=0
D/output lines: {"success":0}
I/System.out: success=0
```

`insert2.php`

```
<?php
include 'dbconfig.php';
$con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if (!$con) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$id=$_POST["id"];
$nilai=$_POST["nilai"];

$success=0;
$sql = "INSERT INTO  nilai_3 (id, nilai) 
VALUES ('$id','$nilai)";

if(mysqli_query($con, $sql))
{
$success=1;
}
$response["success"]=$success;
die(json_encode($response));
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

`button onClick`

```
int size = adapter3.getCount();
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray();
for (int i=0;i<size;i++){
    id = String.valueOf(adapter3.getItem(i));
    nilai = String.valueOf(adapter3.getItem(i).getRatingStar());
    new PostDataTOServer().execute();
}
```

Comment: `'$nilai` is missing a `'`and would be then `('$id','$nilai')`

Comment: btw you should also use prepared statements for protection against `sql-injections`

Comment: @Blueblazer172 i have fix that `'`, and thanks for the suggest about possible `sql-injections`, but i don't mind, and now i don't know why the database goes wrong to save the value

Comment: all `'` should be `

Comment: @Blueblazer172 so i can't use `'` but need to replace with ` sir??

Comment: yeah you got that right

Answer (score 0):

You need to put these headers in your php api

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');
```